# Block a site from search engine - DuckDuckGo

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt, duckduckgo

I have a development site `https://text-domain.example`.
When I go to https://duckduckgo.com and search for `text-domain.example`, it does return results.

*What have I tried so far:*

Created `robots.txt` file with following code(put in in my root directory i.e in `text-domain.example/robots.txt`):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Then added meta-tag like this in my template file:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Even after doing this, I searched on DuckDuckGo and it yielded the same result. Any suggestions would be welcome.

PS.

after waiting for few days there are 2 findings:

- Still, the search results are fetched.
- But I see an message for that result saying: "We would like to show
  you a description here but the site won't allow us."

Is it possible to completely block from showing in the results?

Comment: How long did you wait? It's not going to be instantaneous.

Comment: @juhana oh, how long does it take, i did that some 3 hours back

Comment: You need to wait until the crawler comes back to the site. Could take several days.

Comment: By using NOINDEX and NOFOLLOW in the META tag of your index.html file, you are telling robots that you don't want them to crawl your site.  Change that to INDEX and FOLLOW, respectively if you want your site to be included in search engine results.  Moreover, the robots.txt file should allow all 'bots to crawl your site with the following two lines: User-agent: * // Disallow: // (replace "//" with EOL character(s), as Stack Exchange swallows EOL characters in comments.)  The Disallow: line should be blank after the colon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DuckDuckGo should honour your `robots.txt`. Their bot `DuckDuckBot` is documented at https://duckduckgo.com/duckduckbot.

But note: the DuckDuckGo bot isn’t crawling everything itself (as DuckDuckGo gets results from other sources), so your pages might still show up if you don’t block the bots of these other sources (like Bing). Refer to [mlissner’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089393/1591669) for more details.

With `robots.txt`, there are two things to consider:

- It takes time until changes in your `robots.txt` are recognized. You have to wait until the relevant bot visits your site again.
- Even if your URLs are blocked in the `robots.txt`, search engines may still list your URLs in their search results (without crawled metadata like title and description).

---

Using the `robots`-`meta` element with `noindex` would prevent even listing the URLs in search engines like Google, but DDG [doesn’t seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079649/block-a-site-from-search-engine-duckduckgo/18108618?noredirect=1#comment26650666_18108618) to support it.

Note that you used wrong quotation marks in your example. It should be

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

instead of

```
<META NAME=”ROBOTS” CONTENT=”NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW”>
```

Comment: Thanks for that link, however I quotation marks looked correct in my actual site, so guess I need to wait for sometime to get my problem resolved.

Comment: Hi, after waiting for few days there are 2 findings:
-Still, the search results are fetched.
- But I see an message for that result saying : "We would like to show you a description here but the site won't allow us." , is it possible to completely block from showing in the results?

Comment: @vimal: Then DDG doesn’t seem to interpret `meta`-`robots` in the same way as Google. [Someone says](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/support-for-x-robots-tag-http-header-and-robots-HTML-meta-tag) that they don’t support the `meta`-`robots` at all (at least in 2012).

Comment: Note that the DuckDuckBot only does maintenance-type tasks and blocking it will *not* get your stuff out of DDG. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 19):

DuckDuckGo is an odd duck when it comes to inclusion in their results. I've done a fair bit of research on this topic across a number of search engines and have had some email back and forth with DDG.

Here's the deal. They get their content from other search engines, as [listed here](https://duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/results/sources/). To my knowledge their search results don't indicate which search engine was its source, so for your content to be removed you need to basically go upstream to all of their sources and get your content removed from there. If that sounds onerous, don't worry — you'd want to do that anyway, right?

DDG does have its own crawler as well, aptly called [the DuckDuckBot](https://duckduckgo.com/duckduckbot). It does **not** honor the `noindex` HTML tag, nor the HTTP header (it does honor `robots.txt`), but that doesn't seem to matter because **no new results are created by the DuckDuckBot**. To my knowledge, this isn't documented anywhere, but I spoke with their staff, which I quote below:

DDG says (2014-06-06):

> We get our results from multiple sources and our own crawler wouldn't be the cause of your [problem]. Our crawler only does very specific tasks, like looking (and not actually crawling) parked domains, spam sites, etc.
>
> If there are results from [your website] appearing on DuckDuckGo and shouldn't be, they're likely flowing from one of our upstream sources. If removed there, then they'll stop showing in our results.

I respond:

> OK, so nothing gets put in your index via your crawlers, which indeed do not support `noindex` HTML or HTTP tags?

They confirm:

> Yep! Sorry for the confusion and, if you see anything out of the ordinary, please feel free to let us know.

So then the only remaining question is how do you remove your content from the upstream providers. For that, I point you to [my blog](http://michaeljaylissner.com/blog/support-for-x-robots-tag-http-header-and-robots-HTML-meta-tag) since it differs by provider. The crux of it is:

1. Use `noindex` HTML meta tag and `x-robots` HTTP tag (for images and such) to tell search engines not to include something in their results;
2. List your entire website in your [sitemap.xml](http://www.sitemaps.org/) file so that all search engines can find it there.
3. Use `robots.txt` to block the search engines that do not support `noindex` or `x-robots` tag.

And for bonus points:

1. Set your `sitemaps.xml` files so they have `noindex` set up (and thus won't show up in search results).
2. Do likewise for your `robots.txt` file.

It's a complicated world.